# I want to convert the functional code below to class component instead. How can I do that?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the functional component below and want to convert it to `class component` could someone please help me out with that?
I want it to be something like this.

```
class CalendarCreateModal extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {.....
```

Right now it looks like this, below code.

```
const ModalData = [
  { name: "Reminders", src: CalendarCreate2, action: "Reminders" },
  { name: "Events", src: CalendarCreate3, action: "Events" },
  { name: "Programs", src: CalendarCreate4, action: "Programs" }
];


const CalendarCreateModal = ({ onClose, history, openRemindersModal }) => {
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState("");

  const onSubmitClick = event => {
    if (openModal === "Events") {
      history.push("/partners/events/list");
    }
    if (openModal === "Programs") {
      history.push("/partners/programs/list");
    }
    if (openModal === "Reminders") {
      openRemindersModal(true);
      onClose();
    }
  };

  return (
    ........
  )
}
export default CalendarCreateModal;
```

Comment: Why ? No one in recently build project using class component. (only for error boundary because there is no other option). What you can't done using function components ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-sea-brg0v?file=/src/Newer.js. This is the sample on how to convert this to class component. Also shown how to handle state and props in same. But still its just for intuition based on code you provided.